# django-tables2: Displaying a dict

Tags: django, django-tables2

I want to display a list of dicts, that is not coming from a model. The list is produced by calling an external API(`GETAPIINFO()`). The dict looks like this:

```
[{"name": "testname", "value": 23}, {"name": "test2name": "value": 123}]
```

My `views.py` looks like this:

```
class Index(SingleTableView):
    table_class = ProductTable
    login_url = '/login/'

    def get_table_data(self):
         return(GETAPIINFO())
```

any the `tables.py`:
import django-tables2 as tables

```
class ProductTable(tables.Table):
    PName= tables.columns.TemplateColumn(template_code=u"""{{ record.name}}""", orderable=False, verbose_name='productName')

    class Meta:
        attrs = {"class": "table table-striped table-hover table-borderless",}
        fields = ("PName",)
        sequence = fields
```

My template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}

{% block content %}
    {% render_table table %}
{% endblock content %}
```

This leads to the error:

> ... lib\site-packages\django_tables2\templatetags\django_tables2.py", line 145, in render
> raise ValueError("Expected table or queryset, not {}".format(klass))

> ValueError: Expected table or queryset, not list

Comment: The SingleTableView has a get_table_data method.  You can overwrite that method in your view and return the API data

Comment: adding the `get_table_data()` function to my view leads to an error: `ValueError: Expected table or queryset, not list` - do I have to alter the list somehow?

Comment: can you add the imports? specifically for the ProductTable

Comment: hm there is no real import except the `django-tables2`.

Comment: what is in your template?

Comment: added the template.

Comment: I cannot figure out what the issue is from here.  Sorry I couldn't be more help.  I would work on trying to figure out what object is being passed to the templatetag.

Comment: The ValueError you're seeing is because the table variable in the *template* is a list and not a Table, here: `{% render_table table %}`. It doesn't have anything to do with how you're retrieving the data. One thing I did notice is your example data for `GETAPIINFO` is written incorrectly, you have a ":" where you should have a ",".

Comment: Try using `{% render_table object_list %}` in the template instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used this in awhile but according the django-tables2 documentation, the data input should accept a list.

```
 class Index(SingleTableView):
    table_class = ProductTable
    login_url = '/login/'

    def get_table_data(self):
        """
        Return the table data that should be used to populate the rows.
        """
        return GETDATAFROMAPI()
```

Where is your ValueError occuring?